Imitating Word's "Format Painter" with the docx python library
I want to do the following and my problem is actually fairly simple.
I have three paragraphs ("source paragraphs") with different formats stored in a Word doc. Something like this:

Title
Subtitle
Body

All of them have unique format properties, in terms of font, font size, space below, bullet/no bullet etc.
Now, I want to open that Word doc in Python via docx, add a list of paragraphs ("target paragraphs") and depending on the need, I want to loop through the list apply the format of one of the source paragraphs to the current item/paragraph in the loop. So what I want to do is basically kind of imitate the "format painter" function of Word and simply apply all format properties to the respective target paragraph.
What is the fastest and simplest way to do that in docx?
Many thanks in advance!
I tried applying the formats with the help of ChatGPT, but it would suggest simply going through different generic format properties one by one which I don't want as there are many. Also I tried saving the three source paragraph formats as "styles" so that I can apply them later on to the target paragraphs but this didn't work as well and it would also show me errors all the time.
